# How do you make a picture bring up a print dialog box when clicked on?

Tags: html, image, printing

I have a coupon I have on my website and I want my users to click on the coupon and then be able to print it. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd need to forward your users on to a page containing just the image and add a bit of javascript if you just want the image printed and nothing else:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="window.print();">
    <img src="/image.jpg" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an onclick event to your image.

`<img src="..." onclick="window.print()" />`